# .htaccess 301 redirect same name

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

How to make redirect for this:

```
https://www.domain.pl/page-title/ to https://www.domain.pl/category/page-title/
```

If i make like this:

```
RewriteRule page-title/ https://www.domain.pl/category/page-title/ [R=301,L]
```

This generate loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to perform a 301 redirect here is the code. remember to place the initial site location first then the new site location second and you will be good to go.

```html
Redirect 301 /page-title/ https://www.domain.pl/category/page-title/
```

Hope this helps. :)